# How to show/hide an array of markers on google maps with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Trying to make one button to show/hide markers on the map. Code creates an array of markers out of array of locations and initially shows them on the map. When I click the button to hide the markers it hides them but when I click it again to show the markers it does nothing. I'm just a beginner but I've been stuck on this for a long time. Please help.

```js
var locations = [
 ['1', 33.727190, -117.851863],
 ['2', 34.094715, -117.773466],
 ['3', 34.143758, -118.782985],
 ['4', 33.732112, -117.845280],
 ['5', 33.136157, -117.156101],
 ['6', 33.875900, -118.034982],
 ['7', 33.871597, -118.242668],
 ['8', 33.979397, -118.047032],
 ['9', 33.710725, -117.859015]
    ];
    var locationsMarkers = [];
    function initMap() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 34.052234, lng: -118.243685},
  zoom: 8
 });
 setMapOnLocations(map)
    }
    function setLocations(locations) {
 for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1],locations[i][2]),
   map: map
  });
  locationsMarkers.push(marker);
 }
}

function setMapOnLocations(map) {
 setLocations(locations);
 for (var i = 0; i < locationsMarkers.length; i++) {
  locationsMarkers[i].setMap(map);
 }
}

function clearLocations() {
 setMapOnLocations(null);
}

function showLocations() {
 setMapOnLocations(map);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 var x = false;
 $("#button").on('click', function(){
  if (!x){
   clearLocations()
   x = true;
  }
  else {
   showLocations()
   x = false;
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `showLocations()` the second time you click the button, which is effectively the same as calling `setMapOnLocations(map)`.  `map` is undefined in the closure or context of the DOM ready function, so you are effective setting the map to undefined on all the locations.

In your code, `map` is not a global variable.  It is only defined in one closure, the function `initMap`.  You pass it to `setMapOnLocations` in that function which is why the locations show up in the first place, but once `initMap` finishes, you lose the instance of the google map.

If you assign the google map to a global variable, and use that in your `showLocations` everything else should work as you have it.

In other words, something like this:

```
var googleMap;  // make the google map instance have global scope

var locations = [
  ['1', 33.727190, -117.851863],
  ['2', 34.094715, -117.773466],
  ['3', 34.143758, -118.782985],
  ['4', 33.732112, -117.845280],
  ['5', 33.136157, -117.156101],
  ['6', 33.875900, -118.034982],
  ['7', 33.871597, -118.242668],
  ['8', 33.979397, -118.047032],
  ['9', 33.710725, -117.859015]
];

var locationsMarkers = [];

function initMap() {
  // assign the google map instance to the global variable
  googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 34.052234, lng: -118.243685},
    zoom: 8
  });
  setMapOnLocations(googleMap); 
}

function setLocations(locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1],locations[i][2]),
      map: map // map is undefined here, so this is superfluous
    });
    locationsMarkers.push(marker);
  }
}

function setMapOnLocations(map) {
  setLocations(locations);
  for (var i = 0; i < locationsMarkers.length; i++) {
    locationsMarkers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

function clearLocations() {
  setMapOnLocations(null);
}

function showLocations() {
  setMapOnLocations(googleMap);  // use the global instance of the google map
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = false;
  $("#button").on('click', function(){
    if (!x){
      clearLocations()
      x = true;
    }
    else {
      showLocations()
      x = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` variable is local to the `initMap` function.  To use it in an HTML click listener, it needs to be in the global scope.

Change:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(...)
```

To:

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(...)
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5q08vy6x/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  ['1', 33.727190, -117.851863],
  ['2', 34.094715, -117.773466],
  ['3', 34.143758, -118.782985],
  ['4', 33.732112, -117.845280],
  ['5', 33.136157, -117.156101],
  ['6', 33.875900, -118.034982],
  ['7', 33.871597, -118.242668],
  ['8', 33.979397, -118.047032],
  ['9', 33.710725, -117.859015]
];
var map;
var locationsMarkers = [];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 34.052234,
      lng: -118.243685
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  setMapOnLocations(map)
}

function setLocations(locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    locationsMarkers.push(marker);
  }
}

function setMapOnLocations(map) {
  setLocations(locations);
  for (var i = 0; i < locationsMarkers.length; i++) {
    locationsMarkers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

function clearLocations() {
  setMapOnLocations(null);
}

function showLocations() {
  setMapOnLocations(map);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = false;
  $("#button").on('click', function() {
    if (!x) {
      clearLocations()
      x = true;
    } else {
      showLocations()
      x = false;
    }
  });
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button" type="button" value="toggle" />
<div id="map"></div>
```